# How to configure my router to redirect clients to use a specific IP address as DNS?

Tags: networking, router, dns

I have setup a local server in my LAN to host a AdGuardHome DNS server that filters Ads etc (a bit like PieHole if you want) on a fixed, e.g. IP 192.168.1.88

If I configure that DNS server to be used in a client (e.g. Windows 10) instead of "Automatic", I can see that machine connecting to the DNS server and the filter works fine. The manual setting allows me to set specific filters for that client (e.g. parental controls) that do not apply to others. All other machines use my router (LinkSYS Velop) as DNS on 192.168.1.1 which redirects to whatever my provider has set.

What I would like to achieve is that all clients connect to the DNS at .1.88 instead of the default at 1.1 and that I can see and configure all my clients on the AdGuardHome interface:

I thought I can achieve that by setting the DNS in my router to the .1.88 address:

[image]

But all that I get then is that I can now see my router in the AdGuardHome dashboard doing all the requests and there is no way to configure the filters by device:

[image]

Should it not be that the router is telling the clients that they should be using 1.88 as a DNS server instead of the router using that address? Or is there another setting I need to apply to have this achieved?

thanks!

Comment: DHCP doesn't have a way for the server to immediately push changes to client devices that already have leases. So client devices might not learn of the changes until their current address lease renewal time comes up (which is half the lease expiration time), and even then they might not notice that the DNS server IP address changed. You might need to reboot all your devices that are using DHCP, or at least sleep/wake them or disconnect them from the network and reconnect them.

Comment: @Spiff thanks! That means however that when I do this setting change on the router, sooner or later the clients should use that DNS Server address automatically and directly go to the DNS server to do requests? Or is there a risk that the router will never push the change to the clients and simply continue to do the DNS resolution for the client?

Comment: If neither the DHCP server nor the DHCP client implementations have bugs, then the DHCP clients should each get the new DNS server address when they renew their leases. I just think a lot of DHCP implementations out there are probably buggy, but maybe I'm being a pessimist.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured I do not need to look at the question if the DNS server on the client changes when I change the setting above but simply at the current actual DNS server config in the clients - since those were provided by the router as well.

So all the clients have 192.168.1.1 as their DNS Server which means that the router never meant to tell the clients which DNS server to use else than the router itself.

So I guess I will have to setup another DHCP Server if I want this issue to be fixed.